# Is there a more elegant syntax to do this in Rebol?

Tags: persistence, rebol

I'm writing a tutorial on Rebol's Object persistence but I'm not sure if my way is the best

suppose %config.txt contains

```
a: 1
b: 2
```

We can then load it with

```
config: construct load %config.txt
```

To save it back to file I use this

```
save %config.txt (pick to-block mold config 3)
```

But I'm not sure this is the most elegant syntax to do this in Rebol so do you have another suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some would say its more elegant to save the entire object. But that would lead to a less easy to edit text file. (I assume you may have humans editing the text file).

A shorter form of your save:

```
save %config.txt mold third config
```

Answer (score 2):

or unnecessarily shorter

```
save %config.txt body-of config
```

I don't think mold is necessary, if you mold it then it will be a string and you will need to load it twice

```
save %config.txt mold third config
t: load %config.txt
? t
>> T is a string of value: {[a: 1 b: 2]} ;you need to load this string to make it a block

t: load load %config.txt
? t
>> T is a block of value: [a: 1 b: "x"] ;so t can be used to construct an object
```

So, simply don't use mold.